# Bash Loops: How to execute once, then move to the next iteration

Tags: linux, bash

I've never actually had an instance where this was required, but here I am...

What I've (unfortunately) got is an output of netstat -nr (almost 6000 individual static routes).

I need to take that file, and eventually translate each line into a new 'ip route add' command once I've got this working.

Here's my failcode (echos at the bottom are for testing -> I'd want to substitute them for ip route add once this works):

```
num=`cat $logfile | wc -l`
echo $num
echo " "
for ((i=0; i<=$num; i++))
do

dst=$(awk '{print$1}' $logfile)
gw=$(awk '{print$2}' $logfile)
mask=$(awk '{print$3}' $logfile)
echo $dst
echo $gw
echo $mask
echo " "
done
```

The output, instead of looking like:
Destination Gateway Netmask
looks like:

Destination Destination Destination Destination

Gateway Gateway Gateway Gateway

Netmask Netmask Netmask Netmask

How do I make it so that each time it runs, each output is a single DST/GW/netmask that I can feed into a command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in AWK:

```
awk '{print "echo",$1,$2,$3}' $logfile | sh -x
```

Now replace echo with whatever command you need to run

Comment: No need for the space after `echo`, the comma gives you that for free.

Comment: You might want to add `NR>1` before the `{` to avoid adding a route for the header line, which apparently is the first line of your log file.

Answer (score 3):

Your loops are inside out. Your awk commands process the whole file each time and they're done.

If you need the values in variables replace almost all of your script with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r dst gw mask _
do
    echo "$dst $gw $mask"    # substitute your command here
done < "$logfile"
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis - I've got it working with what anttix provided so I'll give it to him, but thank you anyways :)